# How to set RELATIVE PATH with python in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio, relative-path

[My Directory Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RxB1.png)
I'm studying OpenCV with Visual Studio. But I have a issue that only apply to Visual Studio.
First of all, this is sample code I made.

```
img = cv2.imread('../data/Lena.png')
```

Of course, the variable `img` doesn't return `None` in command line. [Output in Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEDu4.png)
But, as you can see it doesn't work in Visual Studio.(I used assert statement to check whether `img` is None or not) [Output in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LxgE.png)

I assume that the start point of debugging is different from the command `python [file.py]`. How can I resolve this problem? There were no problems when it comes to setting the absolute path.

Comment: I would try confirming where VS is currently trying to run from first. you can use `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Thank you. I just check out where VS starts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the settings for the microsoft python extension there is a Testing: CWD item.  this allows you to set the CWD for tests.  (python.testing.cwd)

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck in your python journey